# Cannot deploy to App Engine

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, google-plugin-eclipse

I have a Web project named "Projxyz" and EAR named "ProjxyzEAR" that I can deploy to a local server but when I try to deploy the EAR using "Google->Deploy to App Engine" I get "ProjxyzEAR is not an App Engine project".

Also, when I try to use "Google App Engine WTP->Deploy Project to Remote Server" I get 404 Not Found, This application does not exist (app_id=u'xyz').

I do have a project created on my console and the Project ID is "xyz".

The same e-mail address appears on the status bar in Eclipse as my Google Account ID.

All the config files in the Eclipse project and EAR project are using the correct Application, "xyz".

The whole thing is a simple "Hello, World" sample app.

What am I missing???

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Looking at the info the developer console returns me, "Project ID must be between 6 and 30 characters."  So I'd be surprised if you have a project name xyz.  Or did you put xyz as a placeholder for your real project name?

Comment: Good catch, but yes it is just a placeholder.  The real project id is "totshm". BTW, I also have brand new dev env with Luna and all libs and SDKs hot off the presses. Which, as we know, sometimes is part of the problem.